# How to save Date to SQL Database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

This is my code:

```
    Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    d = txtDate.Text
    Try
        Dim sql = "SELECT Date FROM tblTeacherInfo WHERE Date = '" & txtDate.Text & "'"
        con = connectDB()

        con.Open()

        mycommand = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader
        If dr.Read = True Then
            Try
                If txtReceived.TextLength < 8 Then
                    MsgBox("RFID # should be at least 8 characters in length.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "String Size Specification")
                    con.Close()
                Else
                    con.Close()
                    con.Open()
                    mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into tblTeacherInfo (Date) values ('" & txtDate.Text & "')", con)
                    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("New Patron added to the database.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "CIETI - Information System")
                    ds.Tables("tblTeacherInfo").Rows.Clear()
                    con.Close()
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Data not save.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "CIETI - Information System")
                con.Close()
                Exit Sub
            End Try
        Else
            MsgBox("Name Already exist", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "CIETI - Information System")
            ds.Tables("tblTeacherInfo").Rows.Clear()
            'Exit Sub
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Please enter numbers only", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "CIETI - Information System")
        Exit Sub
    End Try


    If con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Close()
    End If
```

I have error in saving `Date`, 
When i run this, it always goes to Last part of

> Catch ex as Exception "Please enter numbers only".

Is there any easy way to save the Date to database?

Comment: What is the `datatype` of your `field` `date` in you database? To see what error really is, try to change `MsgBox("Please enter number only")` to `MsgBox(ex.Message)`.

Comment: i use DateTime :D what should I use?

Comment: See my updated comment.

Comment: theres another error, invalid column name "Date". but i checked my database its correct..

Comment: Because `Date` is a reserved word in SQL. So try to insert `[]` to `Date`, try something like this, `[(Date)]`.

Comment: And also read about this Documentation about MYSQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: Why are you using a `TextBox` for dates rather than a `DateTimePicker`?

Comment: this is for rfid tap card system, if they tap the ID, it will be saved to database with the date, i just cant code the save button because of the invalid column name issue :D thank you for your help i appreciate it.

Comment: btw how about the data type ? is it okay to sue dateTime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert parameter.

```
 mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into tblTeacherInfo [(Date)] values (@Date)", con)

 mycommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Date", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime, .Value = txtDate.Text})
```

Or try adding some `Square Brackets` `[]` to you field, Because `Date` is a reserved word in SQL.

```
mycommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblTeacherInfo [(Date)] values ('" & txtDate.Text & "')", con)
```

Comment: The quoted identifier in MySQL is the back tick (`) on my US keyboard it is below the tilde (~).

Comment: Yes it is, ``Date`` something like that.

Comment: Can't add what is should look like because the back tick in SO comments indicates code. So back tick symbol Date back tick symbol. Just surround Date with a preceding and ending back tick.

Comment: This is my problem too. Cannot display `Backtick` to see what really is look like. (`)  adding in the beginning of the field and in the end.

Comment: And don't forget to remove the parenthesis.